# A natural morphism between $\operatorname{Proj}S$ and $\operatorname{Spec}A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Suppose $S$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra. I'd like to describe a natural morphism between $\operatorname{Proj}S$ and $\operatorname{Spec}A$.

In exercise 6.3.F in Vakil's AG notes, we show that morphisms $X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A$ are in natural bijections with ring morphisms $A\rightarrow\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X,X)$.

Why does this result gives us the desired natural morphism?

Comment: Can you think of a way that $A$ sits inside $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$?

Comment: Do you know what $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X,X)$ is for $X=\text{Proj} S$? This is in Vakil somewhere. If you do, you should find that there is a natural ring morphism from $A$ to $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X,X)$ which induces the desired morphism of schemes.

Comment: @KReiser If $X$ were affine I could, because the global sections would be the underlying ring, but I am having trouble doing that here.

Comment: $\operatorname{Proj} S$ is covered by a nice collection of affine schemes. Do you remember what this cover is? How does $A$ sit inside the global sections of each of these particularly nice affine schemes?

Comment: @KReiser It is covered by $\operatorname{Spec}(S_f)_0$, where $f$ ranges over homogeneous elements in $S_+$ and the subscript $0$ denotes the $0$th homogeneous component. I am not sure how $A$ sits in the global section of these

Comment: Well, $A\subset S$ is of degree zero, right?

Comment: I see, so then we get that $A$ sits inside $\mathcal{O}_X$ by the restriction maps?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd phrase it that way, but yes, we get that $A$ sits inside the global sections because it sits inside each $\mathcal{O}_X(\operatorname{Spec} (S_f)_0)$ and glues correctly. For full details, see the duplicate.